# How to compute validation accuracy over entire data at the end of each epoch?

Tags: keras

In Keras, the validation accuracy at the end of each epoch is calculated by taking the average over all batches. However, I would like this computation to take the entire validation data into account. How can I do that?

Comment: I don't understand, the validation accuracy does consider all the validation data into account already, what exact problem are you having with it?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro: Validation accuracy at the end of each epoch, as I understand, is calculated by taking the average over all accuracies obtained per batch. So, if my batch size = 16, it calculates the accuracy for every 16 samples and then averages them. In my case, the 'accuracy' is a custom metric that calculates correlation between true and predicted values. So, the metric is invalid unless calculated over all the samples in the validation set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible, for this you need to use a class that was recently added to Keras: `keras.metrics.Metric`. With it you can implement a stateful metric, and accumulate results over batches (even accumulate the per-batch results themselves), and then compute the final result.

For this you need to subclass `keras.metrics.Metric` and implement the following methods:

- `update_state`: Updates the metric state, here you basically accumulate per-batch results. You can use `self.add_weight` to get updatable variables, if you use another method to define your state, you also have to implement `reset_states`.
- `result`: Compute and return the final metric given all the per-batch results.

Then you make an instance of your metric and pass it to `model.compile`. There are many examples of metrics implemented using this framework [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/metrics.py#L34).